# Bug? ORB returns more features than model allows

Tags: python, opencv, feature-detection, orb

I want to compare feature vectors of different images for image recognition. The feature vectors are extracted with the following code:

```py
orb = cv.ORB_create(nfeatures=500)
img = cv.imread(file, 0)
kp, des = orb.detectAndCompute(img, None)
```

The des-vector containing the descriptors/features should now be of shape 
`(500x32)` and it usually is. But in around 20% of the cases I get a feature vector like `(501x32)` or `(502x32)`.

How can it happen that opencv returns more than `nfeatures`?

Comment: It's been a while. Couldn't resolve the issue. But the features were or at least can be sorted sorted by importance. So if you need to process exactly nfeatures, just clip off the trailing ones.